# "Drop" <li> hover in bootstrap menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animation

so the problem is, i have to do an animation for hover on bootstrap nav that looks like this:
[image: bootstrap nav, border-top]

And animation i need is the color-line going to the bottom of li with the rest of "new" li object that looks almost the same but has it different background color, so something like this:
[image: li after animation]

I realised that it's (probably) impossible to change the position of the border-top, so do i need some other object above every li, that will 'cover' it on hover? I really have no idea how to create that.
Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create overlay with `:after` **pseudo element** and change it's height to `0` on hover. Also you can add `top: 100%` and that will create slide to bottom transition.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #D8D9DB;
}

li:after {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #E3E3E5;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

li:hover:after {
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
</ul>
```

Or you can remove `height: 0` and `bottom: 0` and just use `top: 100%` and you will get something like this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #D8D9DB;
}

li:after {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #E3E3E5;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

li:hover:after {
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
  <li>Link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I had no idea it was possible without using javascript! Thank you so so so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean but I might be wrong.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3xxwap3d/)

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: #aaa;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i know my english is far to perfection, but thats not it.
What i need is an animation between what you did: the first state - animation when the color-line and other "square" is going down, and the last state

Comment: Unfortunately this is the best answer I can give you. https://jsfiddle.net/qz723h79/